# Retrieve records between particular date range

Tags: sql

I have a table something similar:

```
  ID      SartTime              EndTime            
  1    06-24-2015 08:00    06-24-2015 08:30  
  2    06-24-2015 08:30    06-24-2015 09:00 
  3    06-24-2015 09:00    06-24-2015 09:30
  4    06-24-2015 09:30    06-24-2015 10:00
```

How do I implement a query, where in the condition if start and end time is 
06-24-2015 08:00 and 06-24-2015 09:00 I get first two records, and in the condition if start and end time is 06-24-2015 08:00 and 06-24-2015 09:15 I get first three records. Also in the condition if start and end time is 06-24-2015 08:15 and 06-24-2015 09:15 I need to get first three records

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Declare @starttime datetime = '6-24-15 08:00:00'
Declare @endtime datetime = '6-24-15 09:00:00'

Select * from MyTable
where StartTime <= @endtime and endtime >= @starttime
```

Change the first two lines to adjust the search window as necessary.  Also, I assumed your column is really `starttime`, not `sarttime` - code may need to be adjusted if I was wrong in that guess.

Depending on the requirements of the project, you may want to adjust the `>=` to `>`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see which platform you're using specified, so caveat that the following applies to MSSQL Server.

If your "StartTime" and "EndTime" columns are defined as datetime types in SQL, then the server will do the heavy lifting of converting your query to the appropriate types. Here, you can likely just use normal >, <, = operators in your `WHERE` clause (or `BETWEEN` if you're so inclined) to accomplish what you're looking to do.

As far as the second part of your question goes, if you're essentially looking to include an (optional) 15 minute "lag" into your end times and a 15 minute "push" into your start times, you could use `DATEADD` to do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM [myTable] 
WHERE 
(StartTime >= @startTime AND EndTime <= @endTime) OR
(StartTime >= @startTime AND DATEADD(minute, -15, EndTime) <= @endTime) OR
(DATEADD(minute, 15, StartTime) >= @startTime AND EndTime <= @endTime) OR
(DATEADD(minute, 15, StartTime) >= @startTime AND DATEADD(minute, -15, EndTime) <= @endTime)
```

This of course only makes sense if your data is represented only in whole or half hour increments.

Docs for `DATEADD` listed below:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx

Hope this helps!